# Dataframe query for converting pandas dataframe to nested json

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, series

Thank you for all the help in advance.
I am just advancing in Python programming and need your help in converting dataframe to json.

I have the following dataframe columns and rows as follows.

```
BinLogFilename, Type, Database, Data.col1, Data.col2, OldData.col1, OldData,col2, timestamp, offset.
mysql-bin.006423, INSERT, hybris, Sparta1, null, Greece1, null, 1615546843000, mysql-bin.006423:295851133
mysql-bin.006424, UPDATE, hybris, Sparta2, null, Greece2, null, 1615546843111, mysql-bin.006423:295851144
```

I was trying to create json as follows,

```
 [
    {
        "BinLogFilename": "mysql-bin.006423",
        "Type": "INSERT",
        "Database": "hybris",
        "Data": {
            "col1": "Sparta1",
            "col2": null,
        },
        "OldData": {
            "col1": "Greece1",
            "col2": null,
        },
        "Timestamp": 1615546843000,
        "Offset": "mysql-bin.006423:295851133"
    },
{
        "BinLogFilename": "mysql-bin.006423",
        "Type": "UPDATE",
        "Database": "hybris",
        "Data": {
            "col1": "Sparta2",
            "col2": null,
        },
        "OldData": {
            "col1": "Greece2",
            "col2": null,
        },
        "Timestamp": 1615546843111,
        "Offset": "mysql-bin.006423:295851144"
    }
]
```

Here is code that tries to generate the json,

```
import json, pandas as pd
def my_func1(x, substring="Data."):
    d = dict()
    for key, value in x.items():
        if key.startswith(substring):
            d[key.replace(substring, "")] = value.to_list()[0]
    return d

j = (df.groupby(['BinLogFilename','Type','Table','ServerId','BinLogPosition','Database'], as_index=True).apply(my_func1).reset_index().rename(columns={0:'Data'}).to_json(orient='records'))
```

Unfortunately, I could not figure out the following,

1. How do I attach the `timestamp` and `offset` to each json object?
2. I could only attach nested json object `Data.` block while I could not find solution to attach `OldData.` json object.

I was referring to many examples but could not figure it out. Please let me know your valuable solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. The list 'final_list' should be your expected dataframe to json converted output.

To the best of my knowledge, you'd have apply **my_func1** for 'Data' and 'OldData' separately to get the desired result.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'G:/df.csv')

def my_func1(x, substring="Data"):
    d = {} ; data = {}
    for key, value in x.items():
        if key.startswith(substring):
            try:
                if len(key.split('.')) > 1:
                    data[key.replace(key, key.split('.')[-1])] = value
                    d[key.split('.')[0]] = data
                else:
                    d[key] = value
            except:
                d[key] = value
        else:
            d[key] = value
            
    return d

df_to_json = eval(df.to_json(orient = 'index'))
final_list = [my_func1(my_func1(df_to_json[k], substring = 'Data'), substring = 'OldData') for k,v in df_to_json.items()]
```

Comment: well, i was trying to use to_json as I have NA Type in dataframe cells. I doubt it could be more easier to use groupby to easily handle.

Comment: groupby method requires a numerical aggregating column. If you have one, go ahead. I've edited my answer which might be closer to the way you want this problem solved. Hope it helps.